# An adjective for a place that is noisy

Tags: word-choice

Markets are ________.
I am looking for an adjective that is similar to noisy.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/noisy

Comment: What's wrong with "noisy" or "loud"?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider "[Cacophonous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cacophonous)."

The definition doesn't mention noisy, but instead, harsh-sounds, but I think it's implied and what readers would "visualize" with the mind's eye.  In fact, nearly all the examples provided by Merriam-Webster have loud sounds associated with them:  "clash of steel," "the roar of a cannon," and "the screams of wounded and dying men."

Example from Merriam:

> Florence in the spring is already a cacophonous babel of tourists,
>   guides, and souvenir hawkers clogging narrow streets, crowding ancient
>   piazzas.

— Erik Maza, Town & Country, "Exclusive: Tour Florence's Rarely Seen Palazzo Spini Feroni," 27 Feb. 2019

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ***Bedlam*** might fit the meaning that you are looking for, although it is a noun and not an adjective.

It also connotes confusion as well as noise, which might relate well to a typical marketplace.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bedlam

a noisy situation with no order: 
*"It was bedlam at the football stadium after the match was suspended."*

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps boisterous fits your needs. It means noisy and cheerful

Comment: This is a good *word*, but a bad *answer*: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. Please [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a **published definition** of "boisterous" (linked to the source) and say why it suits the context. If you're an English enthusiast like me, you could even add an etymology, some published examples or a Google Ngram! For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[uproarious](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/uproarious)
(adjective):

extremely noisy and confused